# AWK sum of large integers

Tags: awk

I am trying to sum a list of integers from a logfile using 
    awk

```
{sum+=$1} END {print sum}
```

The problem is that the result is larger than the MAX_INT specified in my limits.h file, so the print returns **3.68147e+09**

Is there an elegant way of printing the entire value of the sum?

Thank you!

Comment: tried gawk's `-M` option?

Comment: i am not sure how to make gawk use the GNU MPFR and MP libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `bc` which supports arbitrary precision arithmetic.  The equivalent of what you're trying to achieve would be:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 inputfile | paste -sd+ | bc -l
```

---

EDIT: As per your comment, if you want to prevent splitting of output into multiple lines, set `BC_LINE_LENGTH` to `0`.  Say:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 inputfile | paste -sd+ | BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc -l
```

Comment: The sum is correct, but the output is split in two lines: 45000000000000000045000000000000000045000000000000000009999999999999\
99999

Comment: i've added a sed for a good output, but your solution is nicer: `code` cut -d' ' -f1 inputfile |paste -sd+ | bc -l | sed 'N;s/\n//' |sed 's/\\//'

Comment: @Alex The `sed` command you've used to _fix_ the splitted output would break if the output is spans over more than 2 lines.

Comment: @Alex A better `sed` expression for that would be: `sed -e :a -e '/\\$/N; s/\\\n//; ta'`

Answer (score 5):

gnu awk has `-M` option, you can try with it. it should keep the precision for you.

The `MPFR and MP libraries` should be used when you compile gawk, not at run time.

here is an example, with or without `-M`. tested with `gawk 4.1.0` on 64bit linux (Archlinux):

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{printf "%d\n","368147000099999999999999999999999999"}'  
368147000099999983291776543710248960

kent$  awk -M 'BEGIN{printf "%d\n","368147000099999999999999999999999999"}'
368147000099999999999999999999999999
```

Comment: The gawk in Centos 7 does not seem to have the `-M` option.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` does not have integral type that is large enough for your data, and promotes the sum into floating point. As far as I know, there is no data type in `awk` with enough precision for what you ask. I.e. the problem is not in printing; awk literally does not have the information you want.

You can try `ruby` instead, for example (it promotes integers into big integers rather than into floats):

```
ruby -nae 'BEGIN{sum=0}; END{puts sum}; sum+=$F[0].to_i'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that AWK uses double, internally, for arithmetic, so beyond a certain limit, you're going to loose precision.

Have a look on this link if it helps you out.

[Adding large number using AWK issue cases](http://dbaspot.com/shell/409693-problem-awk-while-adding-large-numbers.html)